# spring postgresql transaction parallel execution error

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I've created [sample application](https://github.com/bilak/spring-oauth2-access-token-issue) with `spring-security-oauth`. At first there was problem with access_token creation under load when multiple threads tried to authenticate as same user. That was fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/bilak/spring-oauth2-access-token-issue/commit/46061f7e879873495943cbe4b4f2b254cc7bb27a). That resolves issue for H2/Oracle databases. Unfortunately this fix don't work for postgre databse and I don't know how to correctly setup the transactions (I've tried all isolations on `@Transactional` but that didn't worked). If someone can point me to some documentation/blog or tell me how to tweak transactions in postgresql that would be great.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
for `Isolation.DEFAULT`, `Isolation.READ_COMMITTED`, `Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED`
I'm getting this exception:

```
{
  "error" : "server_error",
  "error_description" : "PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where authentication_id = ?]; SQL state [25P02]; error code [0]; ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block"
}
```

what's weird is that for `Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ` and `Isolation.SERIALIZABLE` I'm getting this:

```
{
  "error" : "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description" : "Unsupported grant type: password"
}
```

I don't really understand the transaction propagation and configuration in postgresql :(

Comment: please send full stacktrace

Comment: well exceptions are suppressed by [this handler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/ec215f79f4f73f8bb5d4b8a3ff9abe15b3335866/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.java#L166) but I'll try to update the question with exceptions logged there.